# Chromatic index. Proof.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $\chi(G) $ denote the chromatic number of $G$.

I need to prove that $$\chi(G)\left(\chi(G) -1\right) \le 2|E|. $$

And now I'm asking for help.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something but it is not true for graphs like "star".

Comment: Ok, I made mistake. I mean number chromatic- coloring vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If colouring is minimal there must be at least one edge between every colouring class.